# Css Style not applying

Tags: html, css

I'm working on some basic portal. For that I have downloaded it by google and I'm trying to implement my requirement. In that process, style is not being applied. Please see images, so you can understand the problem.

**Applying in  Theme**

[image]

**Not Applying in portal**
[image]

Comment: Can u please post the corresponding HTML of your portal?

Comment: i know it will work  if make it  `!important` , but why it is not applying

Comment: you got tick box next to `display:block` unticked

Answer (score 0):

look some there might be some other css overwriting your code in the portal.  Try adding `!important` after your line of code.